# Can't post a form to a different subdomain via Ajax (WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity)

Tags: ruby, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I trying to send a remote form to a different subdomain (example.domain.com) from the one of the form (domain.com), but i keep getting the warn `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` in the log, and inspector in chrome tells me that the status of the request is `(canceled)`, with the type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This is the form:
`button_to "Follow", follow_users_url(subdomain: post.user_username_slug), remote: true`

When i remove the `remote: true`, i got the result i was hopping for. Also, when a try to use the same form in the same subdomain of the action (example.domain.com), i got the correct result.

I found a way to share the cookies in all subdomains (`domain: :all` in `session_store.rb`), but i can't found a way to share the token in Ajax requests.

I'm using Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.3 and jQuery 1.7.1.

Anyone can help me, please?

**Edit:**

The problem seems to related to [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). Now i'm trying to find a minimum friction solution to make this (Asynchronous) cross subdomains requests work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your POST paramaters, include the field "authenticity_token" with the value returned by the helper *form_authenticity_token*. (It has nothing to do with cookies).

**Edit** I think you're hitting up against the Same-Origin Policy, which prevents javascript from domain A from communicating with domain B (also applies to subdomains). There is an "override" for this called CORS, which *the domain you are talking to* must implement.

So assuming you have control over both domain A and B, you can work around this limitation. This explains why "normal" requests work while ":remote => true" requests don't. (The CSRF token error is probably inaccurate.) [Here's an article about setting up CORS in Rails](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428) (domain B, in my example).

Comment: Looking in the source code of the page, there is already a authenticity_token field being generated for the `button_to`. `<form action="http://leandro.project.dev/users/follow" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Follow" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Y3oJyRQCbl0o/GnRdJaxBTAjqjwSDZ6PEEtaR6zy+FM=" />
  </div>
</form>`

Comment: I think your auth token is fine, and is an inaccurate error. Evidence points to this being a Same-Origin Policy violation. See my edit.

Comment: I will read the post and get back with the result. Thank you for now.

Comment: I have read the post and understood the limitation. I just don't know how to implement a minimum friction solution for this. I will need to request across subdomains really often, with different controllers.

Comment: I would suggest putting the two cors methods into your Application controller. Then you can just add the filters to specific controllers; shouldn't be too much duplication that way. As for your routes, I'm not sure if there's a way to create a generic "options" route. May be some good advice at http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2011/7/26/Responding-to-the-OPTIONS-HTTP-method-request-in-Rails-Getting-around-the-Same-Origin-Policy/3387 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858741/rails-rest-architecture-and-html-5-cross-domain-requests-with-pre-flight-reque

Answer (score 0):

You can set the authenticity token in both controllers to be the same

I think it is

protect_from_forger :secret => 'long_secret_string'

If both controller use the same token you should be able to post across sub domains or other sites. You do open up some cross site scripting holes though